# Access array index using EVAL in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, eval

I need to access specific indexes and keys of given arrays using eval, but somehow I cannot do so when my "path" is specified by a String. The code and content I am trying to access is bellow.

```
$final_eval = eval('
    var_dump($contents->beneficiarios[0]->nomeOperadora);//returns ok value 'Operadora 123'
    var_dump($contents->$temp_eval);//doesnt work when $temp_eval's value is 'beneficiarios[0]->nomeOperadora'
    return $contents->$temp_eval;
');
```

Now if I use `$temp_eval` with value `'mensagem'`, without quotes, it works fine for the specified json key. (returns '2 users found').

The only problem seems to be when my "path" specifies an array index, as I need to access a value inside given array.

Bellow is the `$contents` value (I already decoded it before trying to access in my code):

```
{
  "sucesso": true,
  "mensagem": "2 users found",
  "beneficiarios": [
    {
      "nomeOperadora": "Operadora 123",
      "codigoBeneficiario": "XXAADD123"
    },
    {
      "nomeOperadora": "Operadora 456",
      "codigoBeneficiario": "XXBBEE843"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to access values such as in my first `var_dump` from the first code spinnet, `json_key[index]->json_key`, passing their "path" dinamically.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you need `eval` for here? It really really shouldn't be used lightly, if ever at all.

Comment: why to use eval, what is the purpose? can you add more details to your post?

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto) and [Jerson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10271741/jerson) questioned, eval is indeed not necessary. I have tried using it because I get each object's path dynamically, and as my first approach it seemed correctly.

Anyway, the problem is that passing a string that contains the denotation '->' or '[index]' doesn't correctly access the object's property.

My solution is to explode the string and then loop as given bellow:

```
$explode = explode('->', '$contents->beneficiarios[0]->nomeOperadora');
$i = 0;
foreach($explode as $item):
    $has_array_index = false;
    $array_index = null;
    $has_array_index = preg_match("/\[(.*?)\]/", $item, $array_index, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL);
    if($has_array_index):
        $item = str_replace($array_index[0], '', $item);
        $array_index = substr($array_index[0], 1, -1);
    endif;
    if($i == 0):
        if($has_array_index)
            $final_eval = $contents->$item[$array_index];
        else
            $final_eval = $contents->$item;
    else:
        if($has_array_index)
            $final_eval = $final_eval->$item[$array_index];
        else
            $final_eval = $final_eval->$item;
    endif;
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

It may not be the prettiest solution, but it's good enough to move on to more important things for now.